# How to use one template of google data studio for multiple accounts dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, looker-studio

I've been looking for a while how to do this:

I have a datasource with the information o multiple clients, I want to create a template of Google Data Studio to show some reports. However, I want that template to be unique and some how show the information per client in the Datasource. Is this possible? Should I use another tool?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved through [Report URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters). This will let you use one report, but change the configuration parameters through the url--effectively using your initial report as a template.

Additionally, you might be interested in [Row level filtering](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering) which can be used to achive a similar goal. The current guide is set up to work with BigQuery, but will work with any other data source.

Answer (score 0):

What's the [Data Source](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6300774)? One way it could be achieved is by email address:

Is it possible to add a column that links clients names / ID with an email address on each row, so that each row will have one email address? If an additional column could be added to your Data Set (e.g. if it's an SQL based Data Source then perhaps using a JOIN with a table that has the contact details of the client) that only lists the email address, then, at the Data Source, you could [filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766).